# Automatically adding a BCC email address to all email sent with Gmail

Tags: gmail, evernote

I want to automatically archive email in Evernote.

Is there a way in Gmail web-interface to automatically send all outgoing emails to BCC address?

Comment: What is the question here? You want all sent items to bcc your evernote email address? Via outlook or on the web?

Comment: @Raystafarian : I added to the body of the question that I talk about the web-interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into settings -> filters.

Add your email address as the FROM address and click "create filter with this search"

On the next screen ignore the thing about incoming mail.  Simply add the address you want outgoing emails forwarded to.

Works for me.